# SSH via /sbin/ssh cannot read RSA-Key-File (running from console works)

Tags: c++, linux, ssh, console

I am trying to connect to a server via SSH from my C++ application (and send a shut-down command). I have informed the server about my SSH-key (updated authorized_keys on my FreeBSD-based Freenas server).

The following console command works instantly (Manjaro Linux console):

```
ssh -i /home/[uname]/.ssh/amd_freenas root@freenas.local poweroff
```

I'm trying to use the following command from my C++ code to do exactly the same:

```
execl("/sbin/ssh", "ssh", "-i /home/[uname]/.ssh/amd_freenas", "root@192.168.178.48", "poweroff", (char*)NULL);
```

When called from my program, the console output consistently says, that my SSH-file does not exist, which is not true, since the direct console command has no issues either (picture shows comparison, upper command was from code, bottom one was in the console directly).
The error output is:

```
Warning: Identity file  /home/al/.ssh/amd_freenas not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

I have tried to change permissions on the file (chmod 600), I tried to move it elsewhere and read it from there. I have no clue why this does not work. The file is my private key, so that should be correct. Can somebody help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nif3a.png)

Comment: SSH is available as a library. Why would you want to bother with invoking a pre-build executable?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Because it's 10 lines of code to send one SSH command. Enough for my purposes now.

Answer (score 1):

```
execl("/sbin/ssh", "ssh", "-i /home/[uname]/.ssh/amd_freenas", ...

Warning: Identity file  /home/al/.ssh/amd_freenas not accessible
                      ^^
```

`ssh` is interpreting the space following the `-i` as part of the filename. You can see that there's an extra space before the name of the key file in the error message, because ssh thinks the name has a leading space.

You should specify the parameter in one of these ways:

```
execl("/sbin/ssh", "ssh", "-i", "/home/[uname]/.ssh/amd_freenas", ...
```

or

```
execl("/sbin/ssh", "ssh", "-i/home/[uname]/.ssh/amd_freenas", ...
```

Comment: You're a legend, thank you. Would never have found that out myself, THANKS! Just tested it and it works with cocatenating the option with the path without blank: -i/home/al/.ssh/amd_freenas